# Jquery data table not working on dynamicaly generated html table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am trying to apply jquery dattable on dynamically generated html table.But it is not working.I am doing like this..

```
    function buildHtmlTable() {
    var columns = addAllColumnHeaders(myList);
    ////alert("Inserted rows");tp
    for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
    var row$ = $('<tr/>');
    for (var colIndex = 0 ; colIndex < columns.length ; colIndex++) {
        var cellValue = myList[i][columns[colIndex]];
        if (cellValue == null) { cellValue = ""; }
        if (colIndex==3)
        {
        cellValue = myList[i][columns[2]]+","+myList[i][columns[3]];
        row$.append($('<td class="cell3" width="100"/>').html(cellValue));
        var quantity=myList[i][columns[1]];
        addMarkeronload(myList[i][columns[2]],myList[i][columns[3]],quantity);
        }
        else if(colIndex!=2)
        row$.append($('<td width="100"/>').html(cellValue));
    }

    $("#example").append(row$);
    }
   // $('#example1').paginate({itemsPerPage: 5});
    ////alert("Inserted rows");
    $('.cell3').each(function(index, element){
    var tn = $(element).text();
    $(element).html('<a onclick=LocateMarker('+tn+',this) href=javascript:void(0);>Locate</a>');
    });
}
        var myList=[{"time" : "abc", "qty" : 150, "price" : 8.504768900000000000, "tot" :76.931176100000010000,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 150, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 450, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 250, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 350, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":62},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":42},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":72},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":71},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":10},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":72},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":10},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":71},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":11},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":41},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":11},
            {"time" : "abc", "qty" : 50, "price" : 8.5, "tot" : 76.9,"id":12},
            ];


    function addAllColumnHeaders(myList)
    {
        var columnSet = [];
        var headerTr$ = $('<tr/>');

        for (var i = 0 ; i < myList.length ; i++) {
        var rowHash = myList[i];
        for (var key in rowHash) {
            if ($.inArray(key, columnSet) == -1){
            ////alert(key);
            columnSet.push(key);
            if(key!="price")
            headerTr$.append($('<th/>').html(key));
            }
        }
        }
        $("#example").append(headerTr$);

        return columnSet;
    }
```

in document ready i am calling these functions

```
           $(document).ready(function() {
                 buildHtmlTable();
                var dtOptions = {
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bFilter": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                bJQueryUI: true              
            }

            var dt = $("#example").dataTable(dtOptions);
            } );
```

html place holder is like this

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
      <tbody></tbody></table>
```

Html table is displaying.But datatable effect is mot coming..where i have to fix?

Comment: Are you getting an error at all? Can you also create a JSBin or JSFiddle to recreate this?

Comment: not getting error and displaying html table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be because of your header definition. You are missing `thead`.

```
$('<thead />').appendTo($("#example")).append(headerTr$)
```

Also at the end of the `myList` array (after the last object in the array) there is a `,` which is not a valid syntax.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AvpN9/2/).

For datatable plugin, the header row should be specified with in the  element

Comment: thank u so much Arun..People like u make this community as a heaven..it is working..i will test it properly and mark it as answer